# Oracle Stored Procedure - Number of heat waves (number of pattern matches in a series)

Tags: oracle

I need to postprocess a Oracle dataset in order to find the number of heat waves.
By definition, a heat waves occurs when the data value is greater than a threshold at least two consecutive times.

For example, given the threshold=20 and the sequence

```
23 31 32 17 16 23 16 21 22 18
```

the heat waves are 2:

```
{23,31,32} and {21,22}
```

and the lenght of the longest one is 3 (size of bigger subset)

My input dataset consists of several sequences; a sample input result set is:

```
 -----------------------------
|  ID   |    DAY   |   VALUE |
 -----------------------------
|   100 |   1/1/17 |    20   |
|   100 |   2/1/17 |    21   |
|   200 |   1/1/17 |    12   | 
|   200 |   2/1/17 |    24   |
|   ...     ...        ...
```

In other words, I have a sequence per each ID and I need to output something like that:

```
-----------------------
|  ID   |  #heat waves |
 -----------------------
|   100 |      3       | 
|   200 |      1       |
```

Here the current version of my stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp (
p_query  IN VARCHAR2,
cursor_  out sys_refcursor
) AS
    processed     processed_data_table := processed_data_table();
    c sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN c FOR p_query;
    processed.EXTEND;
    processed(processed.count) := processed_data_obj();
    fetch c INTO processed(processed.count).ID, 
    processed(processed.count).DAY, processed(processed.count).VALUE;
    while c%found
        processed.EXTEND;
        processed(processed.count) := processed_data_obj();
        fetch c INTO processed(processed.count).ID, 
        processed(processed.count).DAY, processed(processed.count).VALUE;

    END loop;
    CLOSE c;
    processed.TRIM;

    // HERE I NEED TO PROCESS processed TABLE AND STORE RESULT IN output 
    TABLE

    OPEN cursor_ FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   TABLE( output);
END sp;
```

Anyone could help me providing a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Fab.  I didn't see in your post what version of Oracle you are using.  Oracle 12 has some enhancements to this kind of query, but it would be good to confirm whether an Oracle 12 solution would be usable for you.  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I posted an answer that I believe fits your requirements, but it is unclear why you mentioned this: _"and the length of the longest one is 3 (size of bigger subset)"_  What does the length of the heatwave have to do with anything?  You don't mention it in your expected output.

Comment: @alexgibbs I'm using the 12c version

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak The lenght of the longest one is another type of processing I have to perform. First goal is the number of heat waves, the second goal is the longest heat wave for each ID.

Comment: Got it.  I'll amend my answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle 12c, use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```
select id, count(*) "# of heatwaves" from series_data
match_recognize ( partition by id
                  order by day
                  one row per match
                  after match skip past last row
                  pattern ( over_threshold{2,} )
                  define 
                    over_threshold as value > 20 )
group by id
```

#### UPDATE: Also show longest heat wave for each series

To get the longest heatwave in each series, we have to introduce a `MEASURES` clause to the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, as below:

```
select id, 
       max(heatwave_length) "longest heatwave", 
       count(distinct heatwave_number) "# of heatwaves" 
from series_data 
match_recognize ( partition by id
                  order by day
                  measures
                    FINAL COUNT(*) as heatwave_length,
                    MATCH_NUMBER() heatwave_number
                  all rows per match
                  after match skip past last row
                  pattern ( over_threshold{2,} )
                  define 
                    over_threshold as value > 20 ) 
group by id 
order by id;
```

Full example with data:

```
with series_data ( id, day, value ) as 
( SELECT 100, date '2017-01-01', 23 from dual union all
  SELECT 100, date '2017-01-02', 31 from dual union all
  SELECT 100, date '2017-01-03', 32 from dual union all
  SELECT 100, date '2017-01-04', 44 from dual union all
  SELECT 100, date '2017-01-05', 16 from dual union all
  SELECT 100, date '2017-01-06', 23 from dual union all
  SELECT 100, date '2017-01-07', 16 from dual union all
  SELECT 100, date '2017-01-08', 21 from dual union all
  SELECT 100, date '2017-01-09', 22 from dual union all
  SELECT 100, date '2017-01-10', 18 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-01', 23 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-02', 31 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-03', 32 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-04', 17 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-05', 16 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-06', 23 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-07', 16 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-08', 21 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-09', 22 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-10', 22 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-11', 6 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-12', 22 from dual union all
  SELECT 200, date '2017-01-13', 22 from dual )
select id, 
       max(heatwave_length) "longest heatwave", 
       count(distinct heatwave_number) "# of heatwaves" 
from series_data 
match_recognize ( partition by id
                  order by day
                  measures
                    FINAL COUNT(*) as heatwave_length,
                    MATCH_NUMBER() heatwave_number
                  all rows per match
                  after match skip past last row
                  pattern ( over_threshold{2,} )
                  define 
                    over_threshold as value > 20 ) 
group by id 
order by id;
```

Results:

```
ID       longest heatwave   # of heatwaves
-----    --------------     --------------
100      4                  2
200      3                  3
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the results in a output data structure? When processing ends, I need to open a cursor in order to read data from a Java application?

Comment: It's a `SQL SELECT` statement.  You can open a cursor for this as for anything else.  Just put `OPEN CURSOR c_mycursor FOR...` in front of it.  Or, if you want to insert the results into a table, put `INSERT INTO my_table...` in front of it.